# SQL Server 2017 Stored Procedure wants table variable declared but it already exists

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2017

Been a while since I have done any sereious T-SQL. I thought I had this right but I am receiving an error that I cannot figure out the cause of. This is for a stored procedure that is not complex. The code is below:

```
--======================================================
-- Create Natively Compiled Stored Procedure Template
--======================================================

USE Viper;
GO

-- Drop stored procedure if it already exists
IF OBJECT_ID('API.newCategory','P') IS NOT NULL
   DROP PROCEDURE API.newCategory;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE API.newCategory
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Category varchar(20) = null 
WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION, SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN ATOMIC WITH
(
 TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL = SNAPSHOT, LANGUAGE = N'us_english'
)
   --Insert statements for the stored procedure here
    DECLARE @tmp int = 0;

    IF @Category IS NOT NULL
    AND @Category != ''
        SET @tmp = ISNULL(
            (SELECT idCategory
            FROM Products.Category
            WHERE Category = @Category),0);

    IF @tmp = 0
        INSERT INTO Products.Category (Category)
        OUTPUT inserted.idCategory INTO @tmp
        VALUES (@Category);
    ELSE
        UPDATE Category
        SET active = 1
        WHERE idCategory = @tmp;

    RETURN @tmp;

END;
GO
```

The error message that I am receiving is:

> Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure newCategory, Line 22 [Batch
>   Start Line 11]
>       Must declare the table variable "@tmp".

I hope someone can point me in the right direction. I am sure that it is something stupidly simple, I just can't see it right now. A bit rusty I'm afraid.

Just to be clear, the operational goal of the SP is to:
1/ Check that there is actually a Category supplied to work with
2/ If there is then try and get its primary key id (idCategory)
3/ If there is no PK for the Category then insert it and return the idCategory into @tmp
4/ If there is a PK then make sure the active column is set to 1
5/ return @tmp as the result (either the PK or 0)

Cheers and thanks for any help

The Frog

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in this statement:

```
IF @tmp = 0
    INSERT INTO Products.Category (Category)
    OUTPUT inserted.idCategory INTO @tmp
    VALUES (@Category);
```

You are doing an `OUTPUT` `INTO` where what you are output into your previously declare `@tmp` which is declared as an `int`. `OUTPUT` statements can only be against tables, temp tables or table variables.

A workaround could be to declare a table variable `@catTab`: `DECLARE @catTab AS TABLE(CatID int)` and `OUTPUT` into that variable followed by a: `SELECT @tmp = CatID FROM @catTab`. That should do it.

Comment: Thanks Niels. I knew it would be a simple oversight on my part. Thanks for the workaround. It's all the little things you  forget when you haven't used it for a while....